# Unknown Error when Deleting Records using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am using this code which allows me to see my DB records in a table and in this table there is an option to delete or edit the records.
Only I get this error message and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

The error message:

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\Inventaris++\NinjaCodeDelete.php on line 32

The code:

```
<?php
include'Connect2db3.php';

$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action']: "";

if($action=='delete'){ //if the user clicked ok, run our delete query
    try {

        $query = "DELETE FROM BCD WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id']);

        $result = $stmt->execute();
        echo "<div>Record was deleted.</div>";

    }catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
        echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    }

}

$query = "SELECT ID, Categorie, SerieNummer, MacAdress, ProductCode, Prijs, RekNummer, PaletNummer, Hoeveelheid, Aantekeningen FROM BCD";
$stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();

echo "<a href='reports.php'>View Reports</a>";

if($num>0){ //check if more than 0 record found

    echo "<table border='1'>";//start table

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Categorie</th>";
            echo "<th>SerieNummer</th>";
            echo "<th>MacAdress</th>";
            echo "<th>ProductCode</th>";
            echo "<th>Prijs</th>";
            echo "<th>RekNummer</th>";
            echo "<th>PaletNummer</th>";
            echo "<th>Hoeveelheid</th>";
            echo "<th>Aantekeningen</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            extract($row);

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$Categorie}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$SerieNummer}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$MacAdress}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$ProductCode}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Prijs}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$RekNummer}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$PaletNummer}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Hoeveelheid}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$Aantekeningen}</td>";
                echo "<td>";

                    echo "<a href='edit.php?id={$id}'>Edit</a>";
                    echo " / ";

                    echo "<a href='#' onclick='delete_user( {$id} );'>Delete</a>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

    echo "</table>";//end table

}else{ 
    echo "No records found.";
}

?>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    function delete_user( id ){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
        if ( answer ){ 
            window.location = 'NinjaCodeDelete.php?action=delete&id=' + id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I also want to say that I am not an advanced programmer I found this code online, where it seemed to be working for the other people who have used it.
I have some experience with Mysql and php but not with PDO.
I hope u can help me!
thank you in advanced.

Comment: How is `$conn` initialised?

Comment: You have not intialized $conn anywhere. To access a member function, you need to create an object of that class.

Comment: Why do you call this error "unknown"?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
I see in this link different classes. But what do you mean with initialize and creating an object of that class?

Could u maybe give an example?

Comment: You really don't know what means `creating object of class`? Just go and learn it first. It's one of the most basic things.

Comment: ok! was just reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
ty for indicating @ least where my problem lies! Hope i figure it out now!
Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is inside your " `include'Connect2db3.php';` "?

And  with this I'm refering to connect2db3.php and is this file inside the right folder?

Your connection could look like this:

```
<?php
$config['conn'] = array(
'host' => 'yourHostName',
'username' => 'yourUserName',
'password' => 'yourPassword',
'dbname' => 'yourDBName'
);

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['conn']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['conn']['dbname'], $config['conn']['username'], $config['conn']['password']);

?>
```